# Error adding smartdiagram

Tags: errors, miktex

I have encountered the following error when trying to use `smartdiagram`

> "! Package smartdiagram Error: I did not find the smartdiagram library 'core.definitions'.."

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram]{Awesome, awesome, awesome}
\end{document}
```

I am using TeXstudio and have MiKTeX. I believe another user (@percusse) has also encountered the same error.

Comment: with pdflatex engine, smartdiagram 2013/04/01 v0.3 on texlive 2012 frozen there is no error. add `\listfiles` in preamble shows for me [files list](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5596729/)

Comment: @texenthusiast Would you like to see the files list?

Comment: From the annotations in the TeX Live repository, I see that the TeX Live package was updated because some files were in a wrong place. Maybe the same error is in MiKTeX. Look at http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&revision=29642 to see what files were moved.

Comment: @gekkostate If the MiKTeX package is not fixed it's useless to download it again. Just move manually the four files from the `doc` subtree to the corresponding `tex` subtree and refresh the file name database.

Comment: @gekkostate According to http://miktex.org/packages/smartdiagram the package has been updated very recently. Do the update on your machine.

Comment: The 4 library files are still missed after the latest update.

Comment: @Speravir The issue has been resolved now. I updated MikTeX and had to manually download the package until the package was properly synced. Thanks for your help!